# Transfer Data on Navigating Back

Tags: java, android, lifecycle, back-button

I have 4 Activitys. From the home-activity, you can navigate to the 3 others. The Application has sound and a button on each View to mute the sound. When I open one of the 3 activitys from the home-activity, the "muted or not" value is transfered by intent.putExtra etc... When I mute the sound in the home-activity, it works fine, but how can the home-activity know wheter I made a change or not in one of the 3 activitys and mute the sound and also mute the sound when I navigate back with the Back-Button? Is it the right way to override the Back-Button?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your question, you will want to start each activity for result.  Say you have 
A -> B -> C -> D each will be started for result.  Then you can set a result before finishing any of the activities.  Examples of this can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities).

However, I think I know a much simpler way.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but whether the sound is muted or not applies to the entire app?  If so, just set a boolean value in preferences, and check for it in each activity.  You can do so like this:

To put a variable in prefs:

```
  Boolean shouldBeep = true;


  //inside the mute/unmute button listener(or whatever)

  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putBoolean("shouldBeep", shouldBeep);

  editor.commit();
```

And then to retrieve that value:

```
   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
   boolean shouldBeep = settings.getBoolean("shouldBeep", false);
```

Comment: Thank you!
Simple and efficient :)
Sorry I didn't get to this by myself^^

Answer (score 1):

The most flexible way would be for the sub-activities to send a broadcast Intent when a change is made, and then use onReceive in all the Activities.

An alternative is to use SharedPreferences to store state.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like application state, and I'd say this belongs outside of the activity as opposed to being passed around from one to the other.  The simplest way is to have a static class that stores your application state (or some piece of it).  There are many ways to accomplish this, but this is probably the easiest.  If you use a static class, you can set and get this information from any activity you wish.  Here's an example

```
public class AudioPreferences {

private static boolean isMuted = false;

public static boolean isMuted() {
    return isMuted;
}

public static boolean setMuted(boolean muted) {
    isMuted = muted;
    return isMuted;
}

public static boolean toggleMuted() {
    isMuted = !isMuted;
    return isMuted;
}

}
```

Other options are to store this in SharedPreferences, a custom Application class, or a shared singleton that you can resolve from a dependency container (comment if you'd like clarification on any of these).

Answer (score 0):

You have many options.
1.You could [start the other activities for result](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) and when you go back to your main application check what the activities returned.
2.Actually set the android sound volume to mute in the second activity like

```
mAudioManager = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
```

and then check the sound volume in the main.
3.Send a message and handle it using a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) in case you have different threads.
Hope this helps.